# regular expressions excluding a character in the beginning of a word

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Is there a way I can use regex to exclude a character in the beginning of a word but still capture the character if it's in the middle of the word?

example:

```
string="i would like to exlucde :HOkd but not JI:jklj "
```

I know that saying

```
re.findall('[^:]\w+',string)
```

will find all the words and exclude the : but I want to include the : unless it's at the beginning of the word ie find JI:jklj but not :HOkd

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\b:\w+',string)`

Comment: Do you want to find `HOkd` (word without `:`) or just exclude the whole word that starts with `:`?

Comment: What about `\w+(?::\w+)?`?

Comment: exclude the whole word that starts with :

Comment: @Bob what's the expected output?

Comment: What about `(?<!:)\b\w+(?::\w+)?`?

Answer (score 0):

**[updated according to OP comment]** `\w` does not include `:`, extend the part that captures the rest of the word. Use negative lookbehind to and word boundary to check if word does not start with `:`

```
\b(?<!:)\w[\w:]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WQdEPP/2/)

- `\b` word boundary to exclude `:` inside a word from negative lookahead
- `(?<!:)` to avoid matching words starting with `:`
- `\w[\w:]+` word starting with alphanumeric character and then containing alphanumeric or `:`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

s = "i would like to exlucde :HOkd but not JI:jklj " 
words = re.findall(r'(?:^|\s)(\w+(?::\w+)?)', s)

print(words)
```

The output:

```
['i', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'exlucde', 'but', 'not', 'JI:jklj']
```

Answer (score 0):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/pr9z50/1)

```
                        # Below, a represents one or more word characters
(?<!:)\b\w+(?::\w+)?    # Accepts formats a or a:a
(?<!:)\b\w+(?::\w+)*    # Same as above but allows a:a:a
(?<!:)\b[\w:]+\b        # Similar to above but allows a:a:a and a::a
```

- `(?<!:)` Negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes is not `:`
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `\w+` Match one or more word characters
- `(?::\w+)?` Optionally match the colon character followed by one or more word characters

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##DcqxDsIgEADQna84mSAmXdyIhlW7@ANdbMF45coRCql@PTK95aVf@XC8tIZb4lwgeyEy3LrDwltC8ipLZa8no6d5Os7KGtPRVmqx9ycRDq7kgDB4KAz@S3VxHsz9GRzMtUDkAuPDrIFWkEKkjLGoPLwxuheR2rVu7Q8)

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"(?<!:)\b\w+(?::\w+)?")
s = "i would like to exlucde :HOkd but not JI:jklj "

print(r.findall(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a regular expression for this (simplified?) example, a list comprehension will do:

```
string = "i would like to exlucde :HOkd but not JI:jklj " 

filtered = " ".join(
    [word 
    for word in string.split() 
    if not word.startswith(':')])
print(filtered)
```

This yields

```
i would like to exlucde but not JI:jklj
```